# Mosaic plot for a single variable in R like a puzzle not just vertical bars

Tags: r, mosaic-plot

How can I obtain something similar to a mosaic plot but representing just the information from a frequency table for a single variable?

mosaicplot(table(my_var)) works fine, but only shows vertical bars.

Is it possible to obtain a mosaic plot like a puzzle of different tiles instead of just vertical bars? Something similar to this image:[image]

Comment: Probably a heatmap - https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/heatmap or tree map: https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/treemap.html

Answer (score 2):

I had the same question, today. I found out that the graph is called **treemap** and at least two libraries support creating it: *[treemap](https://r-graph-gallery.com/treemap.html)* and *[plotly](https://plotly.com/r/treemaps/)*.

Answer (score 0):

As @Man.A noted, you can create a **treemap** with the `treemap` R package. A simple example:

```r
# library
library(treemap)
#> Warning: package 'treemap' was built under R version 4.1.3

# Create data
group <- c("group-1","group-2","group-3")
value <- c(13,5,22)
data <- data.frame(group,value)

# treemap
treemap(data,
        index="group",
        vSize="value",
        type="index"
)
```

[image]